# How to fix tikzpicture vertical position in beamer frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

In the following MWE I have to frames with the same figure and some stuff below. It works but when switching from frame 1 to frame 2 the tikzpicture element is shifted producing a bad visual effect. How can I remove this shift ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{FRAME 1}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
    \draw (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{block}{Block on frame 1}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Itemize 1 on frame 1
    \item Itemize 2 on frame 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{FRAME 2}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
    \draw (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{block}{Block on frame 1}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Itemize 1 on frame 2
    \item Itemize 2 on frame 2
    \item Itemize 3 on frame 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use `t` as optional argument for both `frame`s; in this way, the frames' content will be top aligned:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}[t]
     \frametitle{FRAME 1}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
       \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
       \draw (a) -- (b);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \begin{block}{Block on frame 1}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Itemize 1 on frame 1
       \item Itemize 2 on frame 1
       \end{itemize}
     \end{block}
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}[t]
     \frametitle{FRAME 2}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
       \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
       \draw (a) -- (b);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \begin{block}{Block on frame 2}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Itemize 1 on frame 2
       \item Itemize 2 on frame 2
       \item Itemize 3 on frame 2
       \end{itemize}
     \end{block}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw=cyan,fill=orange!30] (c) {C};
       \node[draw=cyan,fill=orange!30,below=of c] (d) {D};
       \draw (c) -- (d);
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Use an `overlayarea` environment (adjust the height of the environment according to your needs). This allows you to have other kinds of objects at the end in the second frame and will still preserve vertical position of the common ones:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
     \frametitle{FRAME 1}
   \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.6\textheight}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
       \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
       \draw (a) -- (b);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \begin{block}{Block on frame 1}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Itemize 1 on frame 1
       \item Itemize 2 on frame 1
       \end{itemize}
     \end{block}
   \end{overlayarea}
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}
     \frametitle{FRAME 2}
   \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.6\textheight}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
       \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
       \draw (a) -- (b);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \begin{block}{Block on frame 2}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Itemize 1 on frame 2
       \item Itemize 2 on frame 2
       \item Itemize 3 on frame 2
       \end{itemize}
     \end{block}
   \end{overlayarea}
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

   An animation of the result:

   [image]

   And with some more objects in the second frame:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
     \frametitle{FRAME 1}
   \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.6\textheight}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
       \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
       \draw (a) -- (b);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \begin{block}{Block on frame 1}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Itemize 1 on frame 1
       \item Itemize 2 on frame 1
       \end{itemize}
     \end{block}
   \end{overlayarea}
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}
     \frametitle{FRAME 2}
   \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.6\textheight}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
       \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
       \draw (a) -- (b);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \begin{block}{Block on frame 2}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Itemize 1 on frame 2
       \item Itemize 2 on frame 2
       \item Itemize 3 on frame 2
       \end{itemize}
     \end{block}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw=cyan,fill=orange!30] (c) {C};
       \node[draw=cyan,fill=orange!30,below=of c] (d) {D};
       \draw (c) -- (d);
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{overlayarea}
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

   The result:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the each frame is vertically centered.  One way to fix it is to use `\pause`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{FRAME 1}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
    \draw (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{block}{Block on frame 1}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Itemize 1 on frame 1
    \item Itemize 2 on frame 2
  \pause
    \item Itemize 3 on frame 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Another is to add precisely the right amount of space to account for the difference in height.  Alas, `beamer` does not make that easy.  Frankly it is easier to fudge than compute (about `1.22\baselineskip`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newsavebox{\tempboxb}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\savebox{\tempboxa}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\let\beamer@cramped=\medskip
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Itemize 1 on frame 1
    \item Itemize 2 on frame 2
  \end{itemize}%
\end{minipage}}

\savebox{\tempboxb}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\let\beamer@cramped=\medskip
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Itemize 1 on frame 1
    \item Itemize 2 on frame 2
    \item Itemize 3 on frame 2
  \end{itemize}%
\end{minipage}}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{FRAME 1}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
    \draw (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{block}{Block on frame 1}

    \usebox{\tempboxa}

    \vspace{\dimexpr \ht\tempboxb+\dp\tempboxb-\ht\tempboxa-\dp\tempboxa}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{FRAME 2}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black] (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, right=of a] (b) {B};
    \draw (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{block}{Block on frame 2}

    \usebox{\tempboxb}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in practice the itemize are totally different and I really want to have 2 different frames (i.e with a different number)